# Troubles pulling id from first insert done by stored procedure to do use on second stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having troubles pulling the id from the first insert to use on the second insert. Here's my SQL (I'm using stored procedures):

```
DECLARE @JoinDate date
DECLARE @ID int
SET @JoinDate = getdate()

EXEC Members_Add $(UserID), '$(UserName)', 
       @JoinDate, '$(firstname)', '$(lastname)', NULL, 
      '$(Country)', NULL,  '$(stateorprovince)', '$(city)', 
      '$(ziporpostalcode)', '$(addressline1)', '$(addressline2)', 
      '$(MailCountry)', NULL, '$(mailstateprovince)', '$(MailCity)', 
      '$(mailzipcode)', '$(mailaddress)', NULL, NULL, NULL, 
      '$(mobilephone)', NULL, '$(Fax)', '$(Email)', NULL, NULL

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

EXEC Merchants_Add @ID, NULL, '$(BusinessName)', '$(CorporateName)', 
      '$(contactperson)', '$(OfficePhone)', '$(website)', 
      '$(DirectoryListing)', 'False'
```

I need to get the ID of the record added by the first stored procedure, I read up that you should use SELECT @@IDENTITY instead of SELECT Max(ID) but it doesn't seem to be working...

**EDIT:** I just updated the `SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NEW_ID` to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY AS NEW_ID` and now I'm getting a cannot convert nvarchar to int error... any ideas?

**EDIT #2:** Updated the code again... now I'm getting cannot insert the vaule `NULL` into column 'MemberID' that's the one that `@ID` is in for the `Merchants_Add` procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Have a look at [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY will
>   return the last identity value
>   generated in any table in the current
>   session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns the value only within the
>   current scope; @@IDENTITY is not
>   limited to a specific scope.

Try using something like this

```
DECLARE @ID INT
EXEC Members_Add $(UserID), '$(UserName)', 
       @JoinDate, '$(firstname)', '$(lastname)', NULL, 
      '$(Country)', NULL,  '$(stateorprovince)', '$(city)', 
      '$(ziporpostalcode)', '$(addressline1)', '$(addressline2)', 
      '$(MailCountry)', NULL, '$(mailstateprovince)', '$(MailCity)', 
      '$(mailzipcode)', '$(mailaddress)', NULL, NULL, NULL, 
      '$(mobilephone)', NULL, '$(Fax)', '$(Email)', NULL, NULL

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

EXEC Merchants_Add @ID, NULL, '$(BusinessName)', '$(CorporateName)', 
      '$(contactperson)', '$(OfficePhone)', '$(website)', 
      '$(DirectoryListing)', 'False'
```

Note the use of the @ID

From [@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: From the documentation : Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Comment: Read the spec... ignore my question :D and +1

Comment: I tried changing SELECT SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NEW_ID to SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NEW_ID and now I'm getting a cannot convert nvarchar to in error... I updated the question, can you please take another look?

Comment: You should use DECLARE @ID INT... then after insert SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Check if that works. You need to assign the value to a param.

Comment: Just did it... now it's saying cant insert null into MemberID field (that's where the @ID is in your code) I'm guessing SCOPE_IDENTITY() is returning NULL for some reason...

Comment: Is MemberID an IDENTITY COLUMN?

Comment: It is in the Members table, not in the Merchants table. It's a foreign key to link up to the Members table.

Comment: Yes, in the Members table,Is MemberID an IDENTITY COLUMN?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DECLARE @JoinDate date
DECLARE @newId int
SET @JoinDate = getdate()

EXEC Members_Add $(UserID), '$(UserName)', @JoinDate, '$(firstname)', '$(lastname)', NULL, '$(Country)', NULL, '$(stateorprovince)', '$(city)', '$(ziporpostalcode)', '$(addressline1)', '$(addressline2)', '$(MailCountry)', NULL, '$(mailstateprovince)', '$(MailCity)', '$(mailzipcode)', '$(mailaddress)', NULL, NULL, NULL, '$(mobilephone)', NULL, '$(Fax)', '$(Email)', NULL, NULL

SELECT @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

EXEC Merchants_Add @newId, NULL, '$(BusinessName)', '$(CorporateName)', '$(contactperson)', '$(OfficePhone)', '$(website)', '$(DirectoryListing)', 'False'
```

EDIT: Changed source to reflect needed syntax using the preferred SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and use a T-Sql variable to hold the identity value.  And you should generally use Scope_Identity() not @@Identity...

```
  DECLARE @JoinDate dateSET @JoinDate = getdate()
  Declare @NewId Integer 
  EXEC Members_Add $(UserID), '$(UserName)',  @JoinDate, '$(firstname)', 
       '$(lastname)', NULL, '$(Country)', NULL,  '$(stateorprovince)',      
       '$(city)',  '$(ziporpostalcode)', '$(addressline1)',        
       '$(addressline2)','$(MailCountry)', NULL, '$(mailstateprovince)', '
       $(MailCity)','$(mailzipcode)', '$(mailaddress)', NULL, NULL, NULL,
       '$(mobilephone)', NULL, '$(Fax)', '$(Email)', NULL, NULL

  -- Here get identity Value
  Set @NewId = Scope_Identity()

  EXEC Merchants_Add @NewId, NULL, '$(BusinessName)', '$(CorporateName)',
       '$(contactperson)', '$(OfficePhone)', '$(website)',
       '$(DirectoryListing)', 'False'
```